# Executing stored procedure with out parameter in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_request_info`(in request_type text, in adequeate bool, in status bool, in email bool, in pickup bool, in comments text, 
    in request_date timestamp, in pickup_date timestamp, in email_date timestamp, in psid varchar(40), in dso_id varchar(40), out last_id real)
BEGIN

insert into request_info values(DEFAULT, request_type, adequeate, status, email, pickup, comments, request_date, pickup_date, email_date, psid, dso_id);
SET last_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END
```

I am trying to execute this stored procedure in the following way:

```
$request_info_query = "CALL insert_request_info('invitation', false, false, false, false, '', Now(), timestamp(0), timestamp(0), $student_psid, null, @out);SELECT @out;";
$result = mysql_query($request_info_query, $con);
```

When i execute the above code it gives me the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT @out' at line 1CALL insert_request_info('invitation',
>   false, false, false, false, '', Now(), timestamp(0), timestamp(0), 12,
>   null, @out);SELECT @out;

I had checked other solutions, many had done the same. But I still get errors, any help?

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can only execute a single statement at once.  Use two different calls to execute this code.  e.g.:

```
// Insert info
$insert_query = "CALL insert_request_info('invitation', false, false, false, false, '', Now(), timestamp(0), timestamp(0), $student_psid, null, @out);";
$insert_result = mysql_query($insert_query, $con);

// Get query result
$request_info_query = "SELECT @out;";
$result = mysql_query($request_info_query, $con);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`mysql_query` will only send one query at at time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), and the `mysql` extension is deprecated; you should be using the improved extension, [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), and more specifically the function [`mysqli_multi_query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php).

<s>That being said, I believe sending multiple queries to `mysql_query` simply ignores the queries after the first, so you shouldn't be seeing that error from MySQL.</s> It looks like semicolons in `mysql_query` cause this error. You should also consider explicitly changing the delimiter back after defining your procedure, to avoid the potential for future errors.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE ...

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```